# React JS error messages are shown in console but in the the browser window itself?

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in React JS, I am following a Udemy course, the tutor provides some files and asks to run `npm install` to start. But when there is an error or mistake in my code, I can't see the problem or error message in the browser window but in console or vs code terminal only and the browser screen goes blank instead of showing errors as shown in the image attached. But when I create my own project using CRA it works properly. I want to see the errors as shown in the image not in console window.
[image]

Comment: The messages are probably shown in browser when you run the app in developer mode.